# Using mdframed after a section heading

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, mdframed, widows-orphans

The following is a very contrived example, but it illustrates a problem I am unable to solve with the `mdframed` package. When the `mdframed` environment follows a section heading but there is insufficient room to place the contents environment, the section heading gets orphaned.

Replacing `mdframed` with `minipage` or anything else does not result in the orphan, and changing `\clubpenalty` has no effect.

The same result occurs, for example, if the environment contains only a single line but has a large value for `skipabove` or `innertopmargin`; the non-breakable content I use in the MWE below is just for easily demonstrate the result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\BoxContents}{top\par\vspace*{2in}bottom}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{5in}

\section{Section}

\begin{mdframed}% this orphans the section heading
    \BoxContents
\end{mdframed}

\newpage

\vspace*{5in}

\section{Section}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}% this does not orphan the section heading
    \BoxContents
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Is there some way I can use this environment following a section heading without manually breaking pages when this occurs?

Comment: We had a discuss about the issue: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8856527#8856527

Comment: I also encountered this issue, and worked around it by using the package [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) instead.

Answer (score 7):

In the chatroom [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) helped me to point out the issue. Thanks for your engagement.

After `\section` normally you don't have any breaks avoiding orphans. Normally implies we have exceptions.

To allow colour specification you are buying an unwanted breakpoint. To demonstrate this I use the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\showoutput\setbox0\vbox{%
\section{Section}

\penalty10000
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    top\par\vspace*{2in}bottom
\end{minipage}
}\showbox0
\end{document}
```

In the `log` file you will find:

```
.\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\protect \contentsline {section}{\protect \numberline
 \ETC.}
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 9.90276 plus 0.86108
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
.\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921
```

Now we modify the example in this way that we use `mdframed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\showoutput\setbox0\vbox{%
\section{Section}

\penalty10000

\begingroup\color{red}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    top\par\vspace*{2in}bottom
\end{minipage}
\endgroup
}\showbox0

\showoutput\setbox0\vbox{
\section{Sectionaa}

\penalty10000
\begin{mdframed}% this orphans the section heading
    top\par\vspace*{2in}bottom
\end{mdframed}
}\showbox0
\end{document}
```

The output in the `log` file is:

```
.\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\protect \contentsline {section}{\protect \numberline
 \ETC.}
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 9.90276 plus 0.86108
.\penalty 10000
.\rule(0.0+0.0)x345.0
.\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
.\glue 0.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 345.0fil
```

You can see a `glue 0`. There the break happens. I can't avoid the `glue 0`!. Based on your example here the modification of `minipage` which results in the same issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{5in}

\section{Section}
\begingroup\color{red}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    top\par\vspace*{2in}bottom
\end{minipage}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

So the issue based on the color usage.

Comment: Thanks for the walkthrough. I was going through what you went over in chat, and I tried experimenting with some of the definitions in `mdframed.sty`. In the definition of the environment `mdframed`, if I comment out the line `\color{mdf@fontcolor}`, the `\pdfcolorstack` item disappears from the log. If I comment out the `\mdf@trivlist{\mdf@skipabove@length}` then the `\glue 0.0` disappears. However the page will still break at that point. So unless I am missing something, I don't think it is the `\glue 0.0` mentioned in the chat.

Comment: @grizzilus: Good point. I will discuss this issue further on.

Comment: Was a solution ever found?

Comment: @JimParis: Unfortunately not. I tested several other way where `\vspace*{2in}` is replaced by `test\par Test....` and I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I find it really easy to reproduce: https://www.writelatex.com/250587dmfxhc

Comment: @JimParis: Thanks for the mwe. This is really hard solveable. I know the point where `mdframed` disables `\nobreak` but I have no idea how to avoid this. I have the following test: \if space on page < 2\baselineskip then \vfill\eject. So this happens.